# Objective-C - unidentified Error in for Loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

the following code attempts to search for a String given by a cell.textlabel.text in a CSV-File

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//create singleton instance
Globals *myGlobals = [Globals sharedGlobals];

//get searchstring form cell
NSString *stringToFind = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

//get Path of csv and write data in string:allLines
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ITILcsv" ofType:@"txt"];
if(filePath){

    NSString *wholeCSV = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *allLines = [wholeCSV componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    //declaration
    NSArray *currentArray = nil;
    NSString *currentSearchString = nil;

//look for searchstring in 4th line of csv, if found write whole line to a singleton-variable
    for (int i=0 ; i < [allLines count]; i++){

        currentArray = [[allLines objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
        currentSearchString = [currentArray objectAtIndex:3];

        if ([stringToFind isEqualToString:currentSearchString]){

            [myGlobals setCurrentLine:currentArray];
        }

    }


}
```

Working quite a bit with csv-files in my current project I'm pretty sure this should work, but somehow the app always crashes when the function is called.

Through a whole bunch of testing I'm pretty sure that the problem is in the following lines:

```
 currentArray = [[allLines objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
        currentSearchString = [currentArray objectAtIndex:3];
```

The program works with these two lines commented out, but doesnt implement the desired function ;)
I have no clue what the problem might be?

The Error is a SIGABRT in "main".

Thanks in advance everybody.

Comment: When you step through the code in the debugger, what statement is causing the crash?

Comment: Possibly `currentArray` has less than 4 elements. Check that in the debugger - trying to access index 3 on an array with less than 4 elements will cause a problem.

Comment: You're not checking that currentArray contains at least 4 elements, so referring to the element at index 3 may fail.

Comment: before doing currentSearchString = [currentArray objectAtIndex:3]; you may need to check if the array count is greater than 3 and also put break in if condition when the condition becomes true.

Comment: If you were run the App in simulator, probably you would not get any error message. Try to run in device so exact error messsage will throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might crash when your **currentArray** has elements **less than 3** and you are **referring index 3**. So in that case your finding for an index which is out of reach.

So better approach would be

```
for (int i=0 ; i < [allLines count]; i++)
{
    currentArray = [[allLines objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

    // check and then pick
    if ([currentArray count] > 3)
    {
        currentSearchString = [currentArray objectAtIndex:3];

        if ([stringToFind isEqualToString:currentSearchString])
        {
            [myGlobals setCurrentLine:currentArray];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was in fact the problem - an easy to detect problem... IF the console is turned ON. I kept wondering why there were no Error-Outputs but i mistook the "Variable Window" or whatever it is called for the console.

Comment: What is the best way ti initialize the 2 Arrays with the appropriate object-count? "Nil"-is obviously not enough.